# OpenCV wrong image reading with VideoCapture() when switching to OpenCV 4 (aliasing)

Tags: python, opencv, camera, video-capture

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and trying to read and external camera (Leopard Imaging - Autonomous Camera)

My code is simple:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

cv2.imwrite("output.jpg",frame)

cap.release()
```

When I run this with **python 2.7** and **OpenCV 3.4.1** I got the correct output:
[image: output1]

When I run this with **python3.7.10** and **OpenCV 4.5.3** I got the following output:
[image: output2]

I've also run the same code with **OpenCV 4.5.3** but capturing images from an storaged video (mp4) and the first frame of the video **is showing correctly.**